# Creating a term document matrix in java for LSI implementation

Tags: java, search-engine, svd

I am doing a search engine project using vector space model for which i need to create a Term-Document Matrix and then apply SVD on it.

*Should i have the term as the row and document as columns ?*

I am doing it in java so it should be like :

> count[ keywordList.size() ] [ listOfFilesinCorpus.length ];

or Should it be the other way round?. I need to pass this 2D array to apache commons math's  :

> RealMatrix A =  Array2DRowRealMatrix(TDM) ;

where TDM is the term document matrix.

I need the terms as the dimensions and then i will compare the documents in the vector space . Please help , Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, you can always switch between the two through transposition !

But usually, rows are terms and columns are documents

Comment: Haha that was a reply after almost a year :D . awesome I ll accept it anyway